# Swapping Nodes in a Linked List by User Input

Tags: java

*This is a homework problem - looking for guidance!*

I have a LinkedList of objects, where I must accept user input in a test class of which "game number" (aka gameId) to delete. I'm currently traversing through the nodes, and when the gameId = getGameId(), we enter the if statement to make the swap, and bring the node count down by 1. My problem is, I cannot get the elements to swap correctly!

Current Game Id's of objects {71, 41, 31, 21}.

Say the user inputs game number 41 for deletion, I need to change the order to {71, 31, 21, 41} and then bring down the node count by 1 so that only {71, 31, 21} displays to the user.

If I delete 31, I get the output I expect {71, 41, 21}! If I delete 41, I get {71, 41, 31}. When I delete 71, the output stays the same {71, 41, 31, 21} (I think I need to implement a check for when the gameId = getGameId of the 0th node - haven't gotten this far, yet!)

How can I go about getting the swap correctly made?

Thank you in advance for any help.

I've tried so many ways and have googled a bunch, and read previous questions here to try and find a solution and I still cannot get the swap to function properly.

````
``` public void deleteByGameId(int gameId, BingoLinkedList list) {
     Node<E> previous = head;
     Node<E> current = head;
     System.out.println("test ");
     for (int i = 1; i < list.numberOfItems; i++) {
         previous = previous.next;
         System.out.println("test: " + ((Bingo) previous.element).getGameId());
         if (gameId == ((Bingo) previous.element).getGameId()) {
             current = current.next;
             current.next = previous.next;
             numberOfItems--;
         }
     }
}
````

Comment: Why do you need to move the element at the end? I mean just link the previous and the successor.

Comment: You don't have to move `41` at all when deleting it. You simply need to make `71` point to `31`. You do that by saying, "What comes after `41`?" and then saying, oh.. `31` alrighty. `71.next = 31`. That of course is a simplification. But do you understand?

Comment: @Dylan It does make sense, but not the part about not having to move 41. I'm temporarily moving to paper for this one. I have written down 71, 41, 31, 21. 71 is marked as previous. 41 is marked as current, and 31 is marked as current.next. I think this is where I'm going wrong - I'm not thinking of the nodes correctly. Shouldn't 41 be marked as previous as my code goes in the loop when previous.element.getGameId = gameId? Then what would 71 be marked as? Previous.next? Or would that point back to 41?

Comment: @LppEdd, I have tried current = previous.next, previous.next = current.next. Is this what you mean? It didn't work with my code.

Comment: @Ashleigh I'll write a complete example.

Comment: Problem solved by checking for the previous.next.element in the if statement, and then swapping current with previous.next, and previous.next with current.next.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by checking for the previous.next.element in the if statement, and then swapping current with previous.next, and previous.next with current.next.